# .net template engine to produce word documents

Tags: .net, template-engine

Hi all
I need to find out a template engine (something like Velocity or StringTemplate) but that is able to generate formatted text documents i.e. a .rtf document or a .doc or .docx document to be used in word.

Someone can give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution, but if you're pushed for time, try generating an HTML document and then loading that into Word. Most of Word's formatting features are close enough to HTML that it will interpret them correctly. For example, Word interprets a named CSS class as a Word style.